# Unable to restore a PostgreSQL database from a .backup file

Tags: postgresql, restore, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and PostgreSQL. For the GUI, i am using pgadmin4 (browser version). I created a new database and when trying to restore, the following error message comes up:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <title>400 Bad Request</title> <h1>Bad Request</h1> <p>The CSRF token is missing.</p>
```

I Tried using the terminal way using [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-backup-and-restore-postgresql-databases-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial but it does'nt seem to work.

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: "it does'nt seem to work" is not a meaningful description.  What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternartive is using [pg_restore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732521/4453386) command

Comment: I used pg_restore and was able to finally restore it. Thanks @jahmia You made my day!